# Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED

Tags: java

I want to install software, but I got error

Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

although I have installed the required JDK-18

My system variables as follows
my JAVA_HOME is JDK 15.0.1
my JRE_HOME is JDK 14.0.1

Comment: `--add-opens` has been a recognized option since Java 9.  Therefore you must be **using** Java 8 or earlier.  Check what `java -version` says.  Check what `$PATH` is set to.  Check what `shich java` says.

Comment: Also: ... if you are trying to use Java 18, why did you set `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` like that?   And what *exactly* did you set them to?   And what are you actually running at this point?  What installer?

Comment: `java -version` says: java version "1.8.0_241", `shich java` says: command unrecognized.

I've edited `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` to JDK-18

Comment: 1) What **precisely** did you set `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` to?  If you set them to "JDK-18" that is completely wrong!   2) I meant `which java`.  3) In order to change things so that `java` runs Java 18 (rather than Java 8), you need to either change `PATH` or (on Linux, if configured that way) use `update-alternatives` to reconfigure the symlinks.

Comment: I would also recommend that you read a tutorial on how your shell works.  You need to **understand** what `PATH` is doing.

Comment: I think Steven meant `which java` (or - if you're on Windows - `where java`)

Comment: thanks for commenting, finally I had solved my problem by fixing `PATH` through this website [link] (https://www.happycoders.eu/java/how-to-switch-multiple-java-versions-windows/)